# Pagination is only working for 2000 records. I am getting error maximum SOQL allowed is 2000.how to resolve the issue

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

1. PaginationSearch.cmp..................component

   ```
   <aura:component controller="pagiSearchController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName"
   ```

   access="global">

   ```
       <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" /> 
       <aura:attribute name="AccountList" type="Account[]"/>
       <aura:attribute name="PageNumber" type="integer" default="1"/>
       <aura:attribute name="TotalPages" type="integer" default="0"/>
       <aura:attribute name="TotalRecords" type="integer" default="0"/>
       <aura:attribute name="RecordStart" type="integer" default="0"/>
       <aura:attribute name="RecordEnd" type="integer" default="0"/>
       <aura:attribute name="selectedValue" type="integer" default="5"/>
       <aura:registerEvent name="showToast" type="force:showToast"/>
       <aura:attribute name="searchKey" type="String" description="use for store user search input"/>
       <aura:attribute name="defaultShow" type="boolean" default="true"/>
       <aura:attribute name="showButton" type="boolean" default="false"/>      
       <aura:attribute name="currentId" type="String"/>
        <aura:attribute name="spinner" type="boolean" default="false"/>
       <aura:handler event="aura:waiting" action="{!c.showSpinner}"/>
       <aura:handler event="aura:doneWaiting" action="{!c.hideSpinner}"/>

       <lightning:card variant="Basic" title="Account" iconName="standard:account">
            <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <lightning:layout class="slds-float_right">
                   <lightning:layoutItem size="7" padding="around-small">
                       <lightning:input value="{!v.searchKey}"
                                        placeholder="Search Accounts.."
                                        aura:id="searchField"
                                        onchange="{!c.searchKeyChange}"/>   
                  </lightning:layoutItem>

                  <lightning:layoutItem size="5" padding="slds-p-top_medium" class="buttonPosition">
                    <lightning:button label="New Account" onclick="{!c.createRecord}"/>
                 </lightning:layoutItem>
            </lightning:layout>   
           </aura:set>
       </lightning:card>

        <div class="slds-page-header" role="banner">
           <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showButton}">
                    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:home" class="slds-p-around_small" size="large" variant="bare"
   ```

   onclick="{!c.doInit}" alternativeText="HomePage" />

   ```
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.spinner}">
                <div class="exampleHolder">
                       <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading" size="medium" />
                </div>
           </aura:if>

            <table aria-multiselectable="true" class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_resizable-cols" role="grid">
               <thead>
                   <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                       <th scope="col">
                           <div class="slds-truncate" title="S.no">S.no</div>
                       </th>
                       <th scope="col">
                           <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Account Name</div>
                       </th>
                       <th scope="col">
                           <div class="slds-truncate" title="Type">Type</div>
                       </th>
                       <th scope="col">
                           <div class="slds-truncate" title="Industry">Industry</div>
                       </th>
                       <th scope="col">
                           <div class="slds-truncate" title="Phone">Phone</div>
                       </th>
                       <th scope="col">
                           <div class="slds-truncate" title="Fax">Fax</div>
                       </th>
                       <th scope="col">
                           <div class="slds-truncate" title="Fax"></div>
                       </th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   <aura:iteration items="{!v.AccountList}" var="acc" indexVar="count"> 
                       <tr>
                           <td> {!acc.Id}</td>
                           <td> {!acc.Name}</td>
                           <td> {!acc.Type}</td>
                           <td> {!acc.Industry}</td>
                           <td> {!acc.Phone}</td>
                           <td> {!acc.Fax}</td>
                           <td>
                               <lightning:buttonMenu iconSize="x-small" aura:id="menu" value="{!acc.Id}"  onselect="{!
   ```

   c.handleSelect }" alternativeText="Show menu">

   ```
             <aura:if isTrue="{!v.defaultShow}">    
                     <lightning:select aura:Id ="pageSize" class="marginText slds-size_2-of-12" name="selectItem"
   ```

   value="{!v.selectedValue}" label="Display Records Per Page:"
   onchange="{!c.onSelectChange}" >

   ```
         <aura:if isTrue="{!v.defaultShow}">       
           <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
               <div class="slds-col slds-size_9-of-12 ">
                       <lightning:layoutItem>
                          Page No.<lightning:input name="input1" class="widthPageNoBox" value="{!v.PageNumber}"
   ```

   onchange="{!c.setPageNum}"/> of Total Pages: {!v.TotalPages} from
   Total Records: {!v.TotalRecords}

   ```
               <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-12 pageNoDisplay">
                  <lightning:layout>
                   <lightning:layoutItem>
                       <lightning:button disabled="{!v.PageNumber == 1}" variant="brand" label="First" onclick="{!c.handleFirst}" />  
                       <lightning:button disabled="{!v.PageNumber == 1}" variant="brand" aura:id="prevPage" label="Prev" onclick="{!c.handlePrev}" />            
                       <lightning:button disabled="{!v.PageNumber == v.TotalPages}" aura:id="nextPage" variant="brand" label="Next" onclick="{!c.handleNext}"/>
                       <lightning:button disabled="{!v.PageNumber == v.TotalPages}"  variant="brand" label="Last" onclick="{!c.handleLast}"/>
                   </lightning:layoutItem>
                 </lightning:layout>
                </div>
            </div>
           </aura:if>
          </div>
   </aura:component>



   PaginationSearchController..................controller

   ({
       doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
           component.set("v.defaultShow",true);   
           component.set("v.showButton",false);
           var pageNumber = component.get("v.PageNumber");  
           var pageSize = component.find("pageSize").get("v.value"); 
           helper.getAccountList(component, pageNumber, pageSize);
       }, 
       handleFirst: function(component, event, helper) {
           var pageNumber = component.get("v.PageNumber");  
           var pageSize = component.find("pageSize").get("v.value");
           helper.getAccountList(component, 1 , pageSize);
       },
       handleNext: function(component, event, helper) {
           var pageNumber = component.get("v.PageNumber");  
           var pageSize = component.find("pageSize").get("v.value");
           pageNumber++;
           helper.getAccountList(component, pageNumber, pageSize);
       },
       handlePrev: function(component, event, helper) {
           var pageNumber = component.get("v.PageNumber");  
           var pageSize = component.find("pageSize").get("v.value");
           pageNumber--;
           helper.getAccountList(component, pageNumber, pageSize);
       },
       handleLast: function(component, event, helper) {
           var pageSize = component.find("pageSize").get("v.value");
           var TotalRecords =component.get("v.TotalRecords");
           var last = Math.ceil(TotalRecords/pageSize);
           helper.getAccountList(component, last, pageSize);
       },
       setPageNum :function(component, event, helper){
         var pageNumber = component.get("v.PageNumber");  
         var pageSize = component.find("pageSize").get("v.value");
         var totalPages = component.get("v.TotalPages");
           if(pageNumber > totalPages){
               var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
               toastEvent.setParams({
                   title : '',
                   message: 'Invalid page number!!,The page number you entered is greater then the total number of existing pages.',
                   duration:' 8000',
                   key: 'info_alt',
                   type: 'error',
                   mode: 'pester'
               });
               toastEvent.fire();
               helper.getAccountList(component,1, pageSize);
           }else{
               helper.getAccountList(component, pageNumber, pageSize);
           }
       },
       onSelectChange: function(component, event, helper){
           var pageNumber = component.get("v.PageNumber");  
           var pageSize = component.find("pageSize").get("v.value");
           helper.getAccountList(component, pageNumber, pageSize);
       },
       createRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
           var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
           createRecordEvent.setParams({
               "entityApiName": "Account"
           });
           createRecordEvent.fire();
       },
       searchKeyChange: function(component, event,helper){
          component.set("v.defaultShow",false);   
          component.set("v.showButton",true);   
          var searchKey =  component.find("searchField").get("v.value");  
            if($A.util.isEmpty(searchKey)){
               var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
               toastEvent.setParams({
                   title : '',
                   message: 'Please enter the string you want to search.',
                   duration:' 8000',
                   key: 'info_alt',
                   type: 'error',
                   mode: 'pester'
               });
               toastEvent.fire();
                helper.getAccountList(component, 1,5);
           }else{
                   helper.getAccount(component);
           }
       },
       handleSelect: function (component, event) {
           console.log("in han");
           var selected = event.getParam("label");
           console.log("selected"+selected);
           var selectedMenuItemValue = event.getParam("value");
           console.log("selectedMenuItemValue"+selectedMenuItemValue);
                   var action = component.get("c.deleteAccount");
                   action.setParams({accId:selectedMenuItemValue});
                   action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                       var state = response.getState();
                       if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                           $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
                       }
                   });
                   $A.enqueueAction(action);
                document.location.reload(true);
           switch (selectedMenuItemValue) {
               case 'menuSec':
                   var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
                   urlEvent.setParams({
                       "url": "/"+selectedMenuItemValue
                   });
                   urlEvent.fire();
                   break;
           }
       },
       showSpinner: function(component, event) {
           component.set("v.spinner", true); 
      },

       hideSpinner : function(component,event){
          component.set("v.spinner", false);
       }
   })


   Paginationsearchelper..................helper

   ({
       getAccountList: function(component, pageNumber, pageSize) {
           var action = component.get("c.getAccountData");
           action.setParams({
               "pageNumber": pageNumber,
               "pageSize": pageSize
           });
           action.setCallback(this, function(result) {
               var state = result.getState();
               if (state === "SUCCESS"){
                   var resultData = result.getReturnValue();
                   console.log(JSON.stringify(resultData.accountList));
                   component.set("v.AccountList", resultData.accountList);
                   component.set("v.PageNumber", resultData.pageNumber);
                   component.set("v.TotalRecords", resultData.totalRecords);
                   component.set("v.RecordStart", resultData.recordStart);
                   component.set("v.TotalPages", Math.ceil(resultData.totalRecords / pageSize));
               }
           });
           $A.enqueueAction(action);
       },
       getAccount: function(component){
          var searchKey =  component.find("searchField").get("v.value");  
          var action = component.get("c.fetchAccount"); 
          action.setParams({    
              "searchKeyWord": searchKey
          });
          action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
              var state = response.getState();
              if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
                  var resultData = response.getReturnValue();   
                  component.set("v.TotalRecords", component.get("v.AccountList").length);
                  component.set('v.AccountList', resultData); 
              }
          });
          $A.enqueueAction(action);
      },
   })


   pagiSearchController.apxc


   public class pagiSearchController {

       @AuraEnabled
       public static List < account > fetchAccount(String searchKeyWord){

       String searchKey = searchKeyWord + '%';
       List < Account > returnList = new List < Account > ();
       List < Account > lstOfAccount = [select id, Name, Type, Industry, Phone, Fax from account
                                      where Name LIKE: searchKey];  
       for (Account acc: lstOfAccount) {
        returnList.add(acc);
       }
     return returnList;
    }

       @AuraEnabled
       public static void deleteAccount(String accId){
           delete  [select id, Name, Type, Industry, Phone, Fax from account where id=:accId] ;
       }

       @AuraEnabled
       public static AccountDataTableWrapper getAccountData(Decimal pageNumber, Decimal pageSize){
           Integer pSize = (Integer)pageSize;
           Integer pNumber = (Integer)pageNumber;
           Integer offset = (pNumber - 1) * pSize;
           Integer recordEnd = pSize * pNumber;
           //System.debug('offset'+offset);
           Integer totalRecords = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Account];

           AccountDataTableWrapper objDT =  new AccountDataTableWrapper();  
           objDT.pageSize = pSize;
           objDT.pageNumber = pNumber;
           objDT.recordStart = offset + 1;
           objDT.recordEnd = totalRecords >= recordEnd ? recordEnd : totalRecords;
           objDT.totalRecords = totalRecords;
           objDT.accountList = [select Id, Name, Type, Industry, Phone,Fax, CreatedDate from account ORDER BY Name LIMIT :pSize
   ```

   OFFSET:offset];
               return objDT;
           }

   ```
       public class AccountDataTableWrapper {
           @AuraEnabled
           public Integer pageSize {get;set;}
           @AuraEnabled
           public Integer pageNumber {get;set;}
           @AuraEnabled
           public Integer totalRecords {get;set;}
           @AuraEnabled
           public Integer recordStart {get;set;}
           @AuraEnabled
           public Integer recordEnd {get;set;}
           @AuraEnabled
           public List<Account> accountList {get;set;}
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just For the record OFFSET:offset Works only on first 2000 record you need to change your ways in the code

You need to query all record then in your controller you can manipulate them as you want
you can for example create a map> and divide your results in the lists and each key represent a page number

Please mark this as your answer if the comment helped you if not you can ask me any question you need for more clarification

Cordially,